# Hbase Put timestamp (Java) and hbase shell timestamp

Tags: java, shell, timestamp, hbase

I have the following code:

```
table = new HTable(hbaseConf, targetTable);
byte[] key = "key7".getBytes();
Put put1 = new Put(key);
put1.add(OUT_CF, DATA_COL, Bytes.toBytes("data"));
table.put(put1);
```

When debugging I see that the default TS I am getting for the put object is 9223372036854775807. After the put I see in hbase shell that the TS is 1394640871745 (current time in ms as expected).
Does anyone knows why? How to do the conversion?

Answer (score 1):

Personally I don't know Hadoop, but following code produces same output as the default timestamp of your `Put` object:

```
System.out.println(Long.MAX_VALUE); 
// Output: 9223372036854775807
```

So I assume that the `Put`-object just initializes its timestamp to `Long.MAX_VALUE`. Unfortunately I have not found this behaviour documented on the [Apache website](https://hbase.apache.org/0.94/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/client/Put.html).

**Edit:**

Since the documentation of Apache is very poor (not even explained what kind of timestamp they talk about) I have studied the source code and found my suspicion confirmed:

public static final long [LATEST_TIMESTAMP](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.hbase/hbase/0.94.1/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/HConstants.java#HConstants.0LATEST_TIMESTAMP) = Long.MAX_VALUE;

See also this code excerpt:

```
   public Put(byte [] row) {
     this(row, null);
   }  

   public Put(byte [] row, RowLock rowLock) {
       this(row, HConstants.LATEST_TIMESTAMP, rowLock);
   }
```